# Linking JNI to visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use JNI in a C++ application.
I include jni.h and tried calling `JNI_CreateJavaVM` but I keep getting:
"Unresolved external error" about this function.
I Linked to:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\jvm.lib"
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\jawt.lib"

but it didn't help.
What am I missing?

Comment: You are linking to the correct libraries. Is the error a linker error that says: `Unresolved external symbol _JNI_CreateJavaVM` (note the leading _)? if it is then you could be missing `__stdcall` from your declaration: check to make sure `jni_md.h` is included from `jdk1.7.0\include\win32`.

Comment: The exact error is : unresolved external symbol __imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12 referenced in function ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!
I was trying to link my 32bit application with 64bit java libraries.
Downloading the 32bit JDK and linking to that solved the problem :)