# undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM' windows

Tags: c++, windows, java-native-interface

I'm trying to get familiar with the JNI API but can't get a sample c++ program to compile. I got the same sample to compile and run in linux (after posting the question in the link below) but can't get it compiled in windows; I'm using mingw g++. I've changed all the include paths to windows paths and the jni.h is being located at compile time but not the jvm.dll.

[undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM' linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860021/undefined-reference-to-jni-createjavavm-linux)

Here is the commands I've tried using to compile:

```
g++ -g -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include\win32" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server" callJava.cpp -ljvm
```

and...

```
**same as above with the additional** : -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib"
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'
```

and the cpp being compiled:

```
#include <jni.h>

int main(){

    //firstTest();
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:/Users/Ron/Dropbox/jni/simple/ctojava/win";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Hello");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "staticInt", "(I)I");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid,10);

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

I've looked at many examples but still can't find a solution. Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**: I am pretty sure the the jvm.dll is being located because if I remove the -L"path_to_jvm" then I get the error:

```
mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljvm
```

Like I said, this exact approach works in linux, What else am I missing for windows?

Comment: It can be a problem to link to libraries built with MSVC from g++. See this interoperability post: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers. Have you considered using Visual Studio instead?

Comment: @maba- I have tried in visual studio as well but I get the same result. Do you know for a fact that the jvm.dll is built with MSVC? I would guess that it is not, but it's just a guess.

Comment: @RBI It is built with MSVC. The way the function names are mangled in the export table is a giveaway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you ran into can briefly be summed up as a name decoration problem. The linker couldn't find the function with the given name because it's decorated differently in the `jvm.dll`.

Looking at the initial error you got:

```
undefined reference to '_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'
```

it's hinting at two things:

1. The `@12` suffix at the end indicates that `JNI_CreateJavaVM` supposely uses the stdcall convention.
2. The `_imp_` prefix indicates that this function is from an import library that redirects to an externally loaded dll that has this function visible in its export table.

The function prototype in `jni.h`:

```
_JNI_IMPORT_OR_EXPORT_ 
jint JNICALL JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM **, void **, void *);
```

probably looks like this after preprocessing:

```
__declspec(dllimport) jint __stdcall
JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM **, void **, void *);
```

Now the gnu linker that comes with mingw can work with symbols from `.a`, msvc's COFF format `.lib` and `.dll` directly. In your original command, it only found `jvm.dll` in the search path provided (`-L ...`) so it tried to use that.

The problem is that in `jvm.dll`'s *export table*  the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` function is un-decorated so it looks like a cdecl function. This name doesn't match what the linker expects so you get the undefined reference error.

From looking at the Java Dev Kit, it includes an import library at `jdk1.7.0_21\lib\jvm.lib` which has the proper name decoration for this symbol. Your revised command works because by adding `-L jdk1.7.0_21\lib` to the search path it's now linking against `jvm.lib` and not `jvm.dll`.

Comment: Very well explained, Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Comment: Hello. I am linking to the jvm.lib file and it still gives me this error. Any idea? The command used is g++ "-LC:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112\\lib" -o voce_synth.exe synthesisTest.o -ljvm

Comment: @Renato the `-ljvm` switch appends a `lib*` prefix to the import file. IOW with `-ljvm` g++ looks for `libjvm.a`. Try `-l:jvm.lib` or just passing the filename with fully path as is without `-l`.

Comment: @greatwolf Still having the same problem with -l:jvm.lib. Two things.. I am using mingw64 and java 64 bit. But for some reason it gives me the "@12" suffix which supposedly is for 32 bit.

Comment: You might have to check the symbol table in the jvm.lib using something like `nm` or `objdump`. Make sure the unresolved names are in there. It's possible the mangling is slightly different under 64-bits.

Comment: @greatwolf Turns out I made a mistake during the mingw64 installation. I had installed the 32-bit version instead!  Now I have another problem but i'm searching for a solution. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Got it! after reading the post below I was able to compile and run the sample with the additional link in the compile command in order to link the jvm.lib:

```
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib"
```

Link: [Linking JNI to visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688416/linking-jni-to-visual-studio-2008)

I'm no c/c++ expert so if anyone wants to explain why this additional link is required when it isn't in linux I would be glad to accept your answer.