# jni.h Errors using JVM (Java to C++)

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I am trying to call classes in Java from C++ using jni.h. After some research, I used the following code:

```
JavaVM *jvm;
JNIEnv *env;

JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/java";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
delete options;

jclass cls = env->FindClass("Test.java");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);

jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

However, I am getting 2 errors and they are as follows:

1. "_JNI_CreateJavaVM", referenced from:
     _main in main.o"
2. ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone have any input on how to resolve these issues? Thank you very much.

Java version: 1.7.0_71-b14
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment: (build 1.7.0_71-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit
Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Looks like your code is not linking against the JNI library. How to do that depends on your build system.

Comment: Please post which platform, JDK, and build environment you use.

Comment: @AlexCohn 
Java version: 1.7.0_71-b14
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`JNI\_CreateJavaVM' linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860021/undefined-reference-to-jni-createjavavm-linux)

Comment: @AlexCohn That answer is for Linux. I am using Mac and can also use Windows.

Comment: Have you seen the Windows discussion [undefined reference to 'JNI_CreateJavaVM' windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930567/undefined-reference-to-jni-createjavavm-windows)?

Comment: The bottom line is, you need to give `-ljvm` to your linker, and make sure that the linker finds the correct library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I had to do. I am working on my MacBook Pro and using XCode. I did the following:

1. On the left-hand panel, I selected the project I am working on.
2. I clicked 'Build Phases' in the center of the screen.
3. I opened the 'Link Binary with Libraries' tab.
4. I hit the '+' sign and added the 'JavaVM.framework' file.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the appropriate shared object libraries (`.so` on Linux, `.dll` on Windows) check that you are using the same architecture between your compiler configuration and your set of shared libraries.

If you aren't referencing said shared object libraries at the linking phase, you will need to do so.